# How do I implement instantaneous, yet buffered output in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml, interactive

I am writing a Prolog interpreter in OCaml and I want it to offer the following feature:

- Character-based output is *buffered*.
- Output appears *instantaneously*, say, within 0.05 seconds.
- There is no need to use explicit `flush_output/0` operations.
- Buffer flushing operations are done automatically, but not at every `put_char`.

Here's what I came up with:

- Upon program startup I ...

  - ... install a signal handler for `SIGALRM` and ...
  - ... use `Unix.setitimer` for starting a periodic timer.
- The timer is a real-time timer (`ITIMER_REAL`).
- The timer fires every 0.05 seconds.
- All the signal handler does is: `flush_all ()`.

What downsides does this have?

And if so, which implementation alternatives do I have?

Comment: You might want to stop the periodic timer while your program is idle (or start it at the first `put_char` operation since the last flush)

Comment: @Bergi. Frankly, this sounds somewhat brittle to me.

Answer (score 1):

Basically your code is doing a lot of work constantly in order to flush characters once in a while. So this is an inefficient use of CPU time. You might try running `top` (if on a Unix system) to see how much CPU this approach is consuming.

In the big picture CPU time is amazingly cheap these days. But I wouldn't write code like this--it feels too wasteful. Maybe I'm too old school about this, however.

It would possibly be less wasteful of resources just to turn off buffering of your output files. I'm not sure why you're so insistent on having buffering, since you're not really using it for much.

Another downside of this approach is that you have usurped the timer and alarm mechanism for use by the implementation. So it's not available (or not as readily available) for user code.

If you could be a little more specific about what you mean by "character-based output" it might be possible to think of another mechanism. But I can't think of anything myself right off.

Comment: I get your gut feeling of this being wasteful:)  I'd like to point out two things. First, the costs of `flush_all` is next to nothing if nothing was actually output. Second, the interrupt / signal handler *does* incur *some* costs, but not much: At 20 flush_alls per second, `top` says my process uses ~0.2% CPU. And I'd be happy (and less resource wasting) with anything more than 4 flushes / second.

Comment: "character-based output": character-by-character output, as opposed to the level of whole Prolog terms.