# How to install a specific OCaml branch on github as an opam switch

Tags: ocaml, opam

After I asked a
[SO-question on periodic I/O buffer flushing in OCaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62852066/how-do-i-implement-instantaneous-yet-buffered-output-in-ocaml), I found out that the procedure I was proposing did not work reliably due to a bug in the OCaml runtime.

The good news: the bug was fixed in a development version, which is [available on github](https://github.com/stedolan/ocaml/tree/eintr-again).

Now, I could check that version out... but I'd prefer having a "opam switch".

How can I do that easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, the version of the compiler used by a given switch is governed by one package among `ocaml-base-compiler`, `ocaml-system-compiler` and `ocaml-variants`. These packages can be handled, and in particular pinned, like any normal opam package. Thus, if you create an empty switch (e.g. `opam switch create eintr-again --empty`), and pin `ocaml-variants` to the branch you're interested in (`opam pin add ocaml-variants https://github.com/stedolan/ocaml.git#eintr-again`), you should obtain the compiler version you want in that switch.